# How to plot a curved line in MATLAB using a set of points

Tags: matlab, graph, curve, linegraph, roc

I'm trying to draw **ROC curves** using an existing set of values using the following command

```
plot(X1,Y1,'--rs',X2,Y2,'-*g');
```

Where `X1`,`Y1`,`X2` and `Y2` are matrices that have the same size

However, the lines produced by this command are straight ones.

How can I make them curved lines.

Thanks
Aziz

Comment: `plot` always joins data with straight lines. The usual prodecure is to have data points so close together that you won't notice

Comment: I wrote an answer for you.  Do you require any more help?

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB by default uses straight line approximation to draw your graph in between control points.  If you want, you can **interpolate** in between the points to produce a more realistic graph.  Try using [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) with the `'spline'` option and see how that goes.  As such, figure out the minimum and maximum values of both `X1` and `X2`, then define a grid of points in between the minimum and maximum that have finer granularity.  Once you do this, throw this into `interp1` and plot your curve.  Something like:

```
%// Find dynamic range of domain for both Xs
minX1 = min(X1);
maxX1 = max(X1);
minX2 = min(X2);
maxX2 = max(X2);

%// Generate grid of points for both Xs
x1Vals = linspace(minX1, maxX1, 100);
x2Vals = linspace(minX2, maxX2, 100);

%// Interpolate the curves
y1Vals = interp1(X1, Y1, x1Vals, 'spline');
y2Vals = interp1(X2, Y2, x2Vals, 'spline');

%// Plot the results
plot(x1Vals,y1Vals,'--rs',x2Vals,y2Vals,'-*g');
```

[`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) generates a grid of points from one end to another, and I specified 100 of these points.  I then use `interp1` in the way we talked about where you specify control points (`X1,Y1,X2,Y2`), then specify the values I want to interpolate with.  I use the output values after interpolation and draw the curve.