# Interpolate curve

Tags: matlab, interpolation

Interpolate the following data into a smooth curve in the interval ∈ [−2 4.9]. Plot the actual data and the interpolated curve on the same figure.

```
x| -2 -1.7 -1.4 -1.1 -0.8 -0.5 -0.2 0.1 0.4 0.7 1 1.3
y| 0.1029 0.1174 0.1316 0.1448 0.1566 0.1662 0.1733 0.1775 0.1785 0.1764 0.1711 0.1630

x| 1.6 1.9 2.2 2.5 2.8 3.1 3.4 3.7 4 4.3 4.6 4.9
y| 0.1526 0.1402 0.1266 0.1122 0.0977 0.0835 0.0702 0.0579 0.0469 0.0373 0.0291 0.0224
```

**My current code is...but I'm having trouble doing the actual interpolated curve,would it help putting this data into an excel sheet? First time dealing with this.**

```
close all
clear all
clc

x = [-2, -1.7, -1.4, -1.1, -0.8, -0.5, -0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.7, 1, 1.3, 1.6, 1.9, 2.2, 2.5, 2.8, 3.1, 3.4, 3.7, 4, 4.3, 4.6, 4.9];
y = [0.1029, 0.1174, 0.1316, 0.1448, 0.1566, 0.1662, 0.1733, 0.1775, 0.1785, 0.1764, 0.1711, 0.1630, 0.1526, 0.1402, 0.1266, 0.1122, 0.0977, 0.0835, 0.0702, 0.0579, 0.0469, 0.0373, 0.0291, 0.0224];
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: So you haven't done anything yet and want us to do this homework question for you? A Google search for "matlab interpolation" gives this as the first result: https://au.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html. Stackoverflow is for programming problems that you are stuck with *after reaserching yourself*.

Comment: You really think I didn't researched it, I looked all over my textbook and online, this was my only resort, not even my classmates have any idea. Don't be accusing me of anything. All I was asking was for some guidance not accusations.

Comment: If you are trying to do something with Matlab and you are stuck, the first step should almost always be to Google "Matlab" and what you are trying to do.

Comment: That was the first thing I did, I couldn't find an example with an x and y, data points. I had no idea how to interpolate it. If you're not going to help why are you commenting, all I wanted was hints or a starting point, not the answer.

Comment: If you read the documentation for `interp1`, which I linked in my first comment, you will find examples of exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post that I just recently answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27051100/how-to-plot-a-curved-line-in-matlab-using-a-set-of-points/27051397#27051397) pretty much solves your problem.  However, I'll throw you a bone and help you out.  Use [`interp1`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html) to do this interpolation for you.  What you do is you specify the `(x,y)` control points, which are those points that are part of your dataset, then you specify a slew of other `x` points, which have more granularity and have values in between those values of the original `x` values that you originally specified, and you can see what the output is.

Here are the steps you'd need to perform to do this interpolation:

1. Define your `(x,y)` points (which is what you have already done).
2. Define a grid of `x` points that are further granular in comparison to what you have.  You would specify `x` values that are in between the original `x` values that you have.  Use [`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to generate a set number of points in between a minimum and maximum... which in your case is -2 and 4.9 respectively.  We can hide this away by using `min` and `max` on your `x` points so that you can adapt this to any dataset you want to use.
3. Use `interp1` with the grid of points in step (2) and find the interpolated `y` points.
4. Plot the points.

What I'm going to do is do the above procedure, then produce a plot where I'll draw what the original points that were given, as well as a dashed line that shows the interpolated curve.  I'm also going to use spline interpolation to smooth out any irregularities.

As such:

```
%// Define your points - Step #1
x = [-2 -1.7 -1.4 -1.1 -0.8 -0.5 -0.2 0.1 0.4 0.7 1 1.3 1.6 1.9 2.2 2.5 2.8 3.1 3.4 3.7 4 4.3 4.6 4.9];
y = [0.1029 0.1174 0.1316 0.1448 0.1566 0.1662 0.1733 0.1775 0.1785 0.1764 0.1711 0.1630 0.1526 0.1402 0.1266 0.1122 0.0977 0.0835 0.0702 0.0579 0.0469 0.0373 0.0291 0.0224];

%// Step #2 - Define grid of x points - Define 100 points in between min and max
xval = linspace(min(x), max(x), 100);

%// Step #3 - Use interp1
yval = interp1(x, y, xval, 'spline');

%// Step #4 - Plot the stuff
plot(x, y, 'bo', xval, yval, 'r--');

%// Throw in a grid too
grid;
```

This is the plot I get:

[image]

Cool?